# Can you simply hide the text within a textarea, and not just the textarea itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I wanted say a button next to the textarea that you can click on to hide/unhide the text within the textarea, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could always simply set the text colour to 100% transparent

```js
const ta = document.querySelector("textarea");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  ta.classList.toggle("hidden-text");
});
```

```css
textarea {
  transition: color .2s;
}
.hidden-text {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<textarea>This is some text in the textarea</textarea>
<button>Toggle text</button>
```

Comment: what about `tranparent` color ?

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm out of practice and seem to only recall how to do overly complex things 